# Join self table and get values in new rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I wonder if there is a way to JOIN a self table and then get those values in new rows.

The original table looks similar to this:

```
| id | slug    | parent_id |
|----|---------|-----------|
| 1  | one     | NULL      |
| 2  | two     | 1         |
```

I dynamically generate this query from code which may contain N amount of JOIN statements:

```
SELECT * FROM `permalinks` 
  INNER JOIN `permalinks` AS `permalinks1` 
    ON `permalinks`.`id` = `permalinks1`.`parent_id` 
        AND `permalinks1`.`slug` = 'two' 
  WHERE `permalinks`.`slug` = 'one'
```

This produces:

```
| id | slug    | id | slug   |  
|----|---------|----|--------|
| 1  | one     | 2  | two    |
```

However I would like to get:

```
| id | slug    |
|----|---------|
| 1  | one     |
| 2  | two     |
```

Is it possible to get all new joining values as a new row?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: If you want to get rows of 4 values as you show you will need to use `UNION`

Comment: I updated the question, I hope is clearer now

Comment: @IsraelOrtuño how does the sample data in your table looks like ? Also, when you are replying to someone, please use `@` and tag their names. Otherwise, most likely they will not receive a notification if you have clarified the question further.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya thanks for the tip :) I have added how the original table looks like

Comment: @IsraelOrtuño is it possible to have multiple level deep parent-child relationships. Your current sample data is very small to exhibit the general case. Please add more sample data (with multiple levels, if existing), and corresponding expected output.

Comment: @IsraelOrtuño are you looking to get all the child `id` rows  below their parent `id` row.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya yes, I am trying to do that. There's actually not more content, just more levels of nesting, but that's it

Comment: @IsraelOrtuño please add more rows to the sample input and output. Your current data is just too small and a fine tuned query cannot be framed without looking at possible edge cases (that will be possibly only with more data to check against)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using the same query twice with minor tweaks and generating rows after union

```
SELECT perm.Id, perm.slug FROM permalinks as perm
  INNER JOIN permalinks AS permalinks1 
    ON perm.id = permalinks1.parent_id 
        AND permalinks1.slug = 'two' 
  WHERE perm.slug = 'one'
  union
SELECT permalinks1.Id, permalinks1.slug FROM permalinks as perm
  INNER JOIN permalinks AS permalinks1 
    ON perm.id = permalinks1.parent_id 
        AND permalinks1.slug = 'two' 
  WHERE perm.slug = 'one';
```

Comment: I feel weird using the same query over and over again, no way to convert a horizontal result to vertical?